# Ethan Schoonover's Solarized color scheme does not work as expected

Tags: vimrc, terminal, colorscheme, linux-ubuntu

I'm trying to use [this](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme on my Ubuntu system. I installed the package using Option 1 in [GitHub](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), and modified .vimrc as instructed.

It turns out that the colors displayed are different as in the author's website. C code has the following scheme according to the website:

[image]

The C++ code has the following scheme on my own machine:

[image]

How can I configure my `.vimrc` to have the same display effect as in the website? Or do I need to setup something on my terminal?

-------------Edited-------

gvim displays the color as expected. The only problem is vim on terminal

Comment: 1/ Not working as expected is one of the main features of solarized. 2/ If you need help about the setup of your terminal it would be useful to tell us which terminal emulator you're using.

Comment: How can I check what terminal I'm using? In the comment I left below (to the first answer), I list a command, and that command shows I'm using gnome. And I've downloaded the solarized scheme from this link (https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized). What else shall I do? Thanks.

Comment: configure your term variable correctly and possibly also set `:set t_Co=256`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to take advantage of that theme you must select an appropriate palette in your terminal settings as well.

[image]

[image: screenshot]

If you don't find that palette in your terminal settings (for instance if you are on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) you must install a *solarized* Theme for the gnome-terminal first.

1. Get the repo from [gnome-terminal-colors-solarized](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized)
    on Github
2. create a new profile for your terminal to easily get rid of that color-scheme in case you don't like it
   [image]
   [image]
3. switch to that profile
   [image]
4. now install the color-scheme with `./install.sh` from the cloned git-repo, you will be asked two questions, be sure to answer the second one with the profile you just created

> Please select a Gnome Terminal profile:
>         1) Default
>         2) solarized
>         #? 2

Now you are ready to install the vim-solarized theme.

Comment: How did you open this panel? I opened the `System Settings` at the task bar, and clicked the `Color` icon, it listed the monitor device and and a `Add profile` button. What's next?

Comment: @user3813057 that's the terminal's profile preferences, not system settings.

Comment: @guntbert I'm using gnome term, at least the command `cat /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator | grep exec` shows `exec('gnome-terminal',@args)`.  I've downloaded solarized color scheme from this (https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized) link, and run the `./install.sh` command. However, when I open the palette, there is no `Solarized` option, and the vim in terminal still does not display as expected. What else shall I do?

Comment: @user3813057 Strange, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and the two *solarized* color-schemes are built in. I checked and https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-colors.html.en says so too.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS, which has no solarized-light/dark color-scheme. Is there any other way to set the Ethan Solarized color?

Comment: @guntbert Please modify the answer so that I can accept it. The problem can be solved in the following way: 1. install vim color scheme as in the original post. 2. if the terminal vim does not display color correctly, install the terminal color scheme as in github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized . If there is still problem, the FAQ in that page might help